# How To Change A String In To Google Chart Data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a `responseText` as String in this format:

```
[['0.00',4474.12], ['31.25',1995.16], ['62.50',44.98], ['93.75',16.86], ['125.00',9.10], ['156.25',5.76], ['187.50',3.99], ['218.75',2.92], ['250.00',2.21], ['281.25',1.71], ['312.50',1.33], ['343.75',1.03], ['375.00',0.77], ['406.25',0.56], ['437.50',0.36], ['468.75',0.18]]
```

And i want to change it into array to feed in `addRows()` functions in Google Charts API.

Would you kindly help me to do it with JavaScript?

Thank you so much.

Comment: why not change the request to --> `dataType: 'json'` -- then you wouldn't need to convert the string...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) but since you have ***`single quotation`*** those are considered as [syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse#Property_names_must_be_double-quoted_strings) in `JSON.parse()` you need to replace them first and than you're good to go.

```js
console.log( JSON.parse(`[1,2,3]`))
console.log( JSON.parse(`["1",2]`))
console.log( JSON.parse(`['1',2]`))  // error on this line
```

Working code

```js
let str = `[['0.00',4474.12], ['31.25',1995.16], ['62.50',44.98], ['93.75',16.86], ['125.00',9.10], ['156.25',5.76], ['187.50',3.99], ['218.75',2.92], ['250.00',2.21], ['281.25',1.71], ['312.50',1.33], ['343.75',1.03], ['375.00',0.77], ['406.25',0.56], ['437.50',0.36], ['468.75',0.18]]`

let op = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g,`"`))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Yes, man, sorry for not included data in last answer. My data is here:

`[["0.00",4524.58], ["31.25",2017.66], ["62.50",45.48], ["93.75",17.05], ["125.00",9.20], ["156.25",5.83], ["187.50",4.04], ["218.75",2.96], ["250.00",2.24], ["281.25",1.73], ["312.50",1.34], ["343.75",1.04], ["375.00",0.78], ["406.25",0.56], ["437.50",0.36], ["468.75",0.18]]`

Comment: It has ` , but StackOverflow did not show it.

The error is:

"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ` in JSON at position 0"

Comment: @ĐàoMinhĐức seems to work. i am not getting any error https://jsfiddle.net/y3Lk2rgu/

Comment: I copied your code from jsfiddle and paste into https://jsconsole.com/, here is output:

https://snag.gy/FCZASo.jpg

I think ` is not problem, I am trying to fix it, btw, thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: @ĐàoMinhĐức you can change replace to .replace(/['\`]/g, `"`) this will remove \` too

Comment: This data is receive from a request with content type is "text/plain". Does it affect on the output?

Comment: Maybe a better question: I have a JSON data like this:

{"0.00" : 3717.22, "31.25" : 1657.63, "62.50" : 37.37, "93.75" : 14.00, "125.00" : 7.56, "156.25" : 4.79, "187.50" : 3.32, "218.75" : 2.43, "250.00" : 1.84, "281.25" : 1.42, "312.50" : 1.10, "343.75" : 0.85, "375.00" : 0.64, "406.25" : 0.46, "437.50" : 0.30, "468.75" : 0.15}

And I want to change it into

[['0.00' : 3717.22], ['31.25' : 1657.63], ... ]

To feed in Google Chart Data.

You guys, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `JSON.parse` to convert the text into an array
(if you replace single quotes with double quotes, as noted in other question)

```
var text = xhr.responseText;
var arrData = JSON.parse(text);
data.addRows(arrData);
```

---

**EDIT**

if your data is formatted as a json object,
you can convert to a simple array for google charts,
using a `for...in`  statement.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var jsonData = {"0.00" : 3717.22, "31.25" : 1657.63, "62.50" : 37.37, "93.75" : 14.00, "125.00" : 7.56, "156.25" : 4.79, "187.50" : 3.32, "218.75" : 2.43, "250.00" : 1.84, "281.25" : 1.42, "312.50" : 1.10, "343.75" : 0.85, "375.00" : 0.64, "406.25" : 0.46, "437.50" : 0.30, "468.75" : 0.15};
  var arrayData = [];

  // convert json to simple array for google charts
  for (var x in jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      arrayData.push([
        x,
        jsonData[x]
      ]);
    }
  }

  // convert array to google data table
  // be sure to pass true for "first row is data" argument
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData, true);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: WhiteHat, thanks for kind helping.

I changed your code in to 

var text = this.responseText;

And the JSON return: 

"Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

Do you have any more ideas?